# Why doesn't `undefined` appear in the for...in loop?

Tags: javascript, properties

I'm a little confused regarding `for`-`in` loops:

```
window.hasOwnProperty(undefined) // Returns true
```

and

```
undefined in window // Returns true
```

but the following does *not* print `Undefined is in window!`

```
for(a in window) {
     if(a === 'undefined')
         console.log('Undefined is in window!');
}
```

Why doesn't `undefined` appear in the `for`-`in` loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not an enumerable property. In modern JavaScript engines, you have control over that in your own objects, but it's pretty much always been the case (well maybe not in every interpreter) that "native" objects could "hide" properties from `for ... in` iteration.

You can read about `Object.defineProperty()` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).  I'm not sure whether there's going to be a syntax (in Harmony) for marking properties as non-enumerable in object literals.

Comment: Is there a way to build a function that returns all `x` such that `x in window` is `true`?

Comment: @Randomblue well I don't like saying anything's not possible in JavaScript, but I don't think so here; that's kind of the point of that "enumerable" flag: to prevent "internal" properties from polluting the namespace.

Comment: [Found it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames#Cross-browser_compatibility)!

Comment: @Randomblue: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).forEach(function(prop) { window[prop];});` Looks like you found it already. :)

Comment: See I knew it was unwise to say it's impossible :-)

Comment: @Randomblue: Regarding `window.undefined` specifically: http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.1.3.